# Algorithm Problem: Converting non-integer maximum flow to integer maximum flow

Tags: algorithm, graph, combinatorics, mathematical-optimization

Consider, we have a **non-integer maximum flow** in a directed network with integer arc capacity.

Is there an algorithm that can convert this flow into an integer maximum flow?

And what is its running time?

It is not a homework problem.

Comment: By arc, you mean edge?  I suppose we are assuming a single source and single destination?  Come on, at least show us your effort.

Comment: I think it's NP-Hard (just guess, should think or search about it)

Comment: Sounds like an ILP problem to me which is usually NP hard.

Comment: @ChrisWue: You can formulate it as ILP. But the matrix is totally unimodular. This means the solution found by the simplex method is integral.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a max s-t flow(integer) with integral arc capacities it is not NP-complete.
And maybe there is an algorithms for that purpose. What you would try is to find some
arcs that are not saturated with there capacity. 
On all path that takes this edge has to be an edge that is saturated.
Here you will have multiple s-t paths with non-integral capacity.
Try to make the integral by increasing one and decrease the other without
violating the capacities.

Additionally, take a look at the algorithms at this page:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_flow_problem
All mentioned algorithms should produce integral flows.

It also states the **Integral Flow Theorem:**
 If each edge in a flow network has integral capacity, then there exists an integral maximal flow.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure what you mean by `convert this flow into an integer maximum flow`.
If you have a non integral max flow then of course its not possible to get the same flow from an integral problem, as the solution of an integer graph is also integral.

(E.g. if you max flow is 3.5, there is no way to get this max flow from an integral graph).

If you want just the solution the rounded integer graph. Just solve it again, and then you got the corrosponding integer solution.

PS: Neither integer nor non-integer max flow is NP-complete. They are both in P.

Comment: He/She mentioned integral arc capacities. Thus, the max flow can not be something like 3.5. One the flow on some arcs can have such a value.

Comment: Yes right, thats why I dont really grok this question. Original poster said they have a non-integer max flow. One of the two must be false. Either they have only integers at the edges, then the max flow must also be integer, or they have a non integer max flow, but then the arcs must have also non integers.

Comment: I think the poster thinks of an flow with an integer flow value but some arcs have a non-integer flow. Like two s-t pathes with unit capacity that share exactly one arc and the flow is 0.5 on both paths.

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to the exercise 9.42 from AMO's book. I think it is better to look at "integer equal flow problem".